# Using cloud computing for development environments

Tags: .net, azure, cloud, development-environment

Does anyone have any advice or pointer for utilising cloud computing for development environments. I'm think that I can move on premises servers to the cloud so that we can spin up environments as and when we need them.

All development is .NET so I'm thinking Azure would be used and in particular Azure VM's that would have SQL server and IIS (development will be for Websites and web services)

The idea would be that we could just use environments as and when we need them, paying for them while projects go on and then tearing them down at the end so that we're not paying for them all the time.

But would this really be a benefit over on premise servers for development environments? Has anyone done this sort of thing?

Comment: Yes to all. This is a big discussion more appropriate for programmers.stackexchange.com. For example, you'd better shutdown the VMs at the end-of-day rather than pay for 12+ hours of idleness daily

Answer (score 0):

We have done this, and it worked well. we had the build server run powershell scripts after the projects had been built and unit tests had run to deploy the code to azure worker roles. Tests then ran after this deployment to check that the deployed code worked as expected and the instances were then left up for additional testing of dev usage.

Each dev had a complete set of resources just for them (so unique storage accounts in azure, unique role instances, service bus namespaces etc etc)

We had the BS run a script which tore down every deployment after everyone had gone home, but allowed devs the option of excluding their deployments from this teardown if they wanted (for example if overnight tests were running).

The benefits were that we could test independently, and at any scale we wanted, but on the downside the build/test/deploy/test process ended up being a lengthy one and it would but 20-30 mins before checked in changed had finished running the final tests. This was partly due to many roles being deployed in a single build, and given the time again I'd deploy each role separately. The management of the builds was also a non trivial exercise with some complicated build chains which had to be manually recreated for each dev. We used TeamCity so with something else YMMV.

Comment: Good tip thanks.
I think I may try a custom MSBuild script that will build everything, run the tests and then deploy. It could have target once the deployment is done that will kick off the acceptance UI tests.